# Entitiframework core How to pass context object?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0, webapi

Hi I am working on web api(.net core) with entity framework core. I have created context class as below.

```
public class TimeSheetContext : DbContext
{
    public TimeSheetContext(DbContextOptions<TimeSheetContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TimeSheetData> timeSheets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Week> weeks { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am using below code to add timesheetdata.

```
public void SaveTimeSheet(TimeSheetData timeSheet)
{
    using (var context = new TimeSheetContext())
    {
        var std = context.timeSheets.Add(timeSheet);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`using (var context = new TimeSheetContext())` here I am getting below error.

> there is no arguments corresponds to the required formal parameter
>   options of
>   timesheetcontext.timesheetcontext(dbcontextoptions)

I added below code in startup.

```
services.AddDbContext<TimeSheetContext>(opt =>
              opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TimeSheet")));
```

then I used like below.

```
public class TimeSheet : ITimesheet
{
    private readonly TimeSheetContext _context;
    public TimeSheet(TimeSheetContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public TimeSheet GetTimeSheet(string userid, string weekid)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SaveTimeSheet(TimeSheetData timeSheet)
    {   
         var std = _context.timeSheets.Add(timeSheet);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

then I tried to register TimeSheet service in startup as below.

```
services.AddTransient<ITimesheet, TimeSheet>();
```

Now i started getting error near  Timesheet,

> timesheet is a namespace but used like a type

Can someone help me to find this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You want to wire it up to the DI container and inject it in - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection

Comment: You have a constructor defined that accepts a parameter.  You are not supplying that parameter.

Comment: Use should try to use [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which would avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added code as you said but when I try to register service in startup I started getting error. I updated my question. Can someone help me to understand this error. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I believe you have two errors.

**1. timesheet is a namespace but used like a type**

I believe the TimeSheet class is present in the namespace which is ending with the same text `TimeSheet`.

While specifying your class in DI, you can use fully qualified class 
`<namespace-name>.TimeSheet` to avoid this error.

**2. there is no arguments corresponds to the required formal parameter options of timesheetcontext.timesheetcontext(dbcontextoptions)**

This was coming because you were not using DI for using the DbContext object.

Ideally you should consume the DbContext as below:

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Controllers
{
    public class TimeSheetController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TimeSheetContext _context;

        public TimeSheetController(TimeSheetContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you to resolve the issues.